# Trying to Execute the SSIS package from ADF

Tags: ssis, azure-data-factory

We are migrating the SSIS package from  one SQL server to Azure SQL MI . Because we want to execute  the SSIS package from ADF .  There is  send mail activity in the SSIS Package which is working when trying to execute from VS 2017 But it is failing when  trying to Execute from ADF.

We have set the connectByProxy= True
Check the connection String which is working fine In VS .

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Make sure that SMTP server is accessible in SSIS-IR. Try pinging SMTP server from SSIS-IR server.

Comment: SMTP server is accessible in SSIS - IR   error :     The task has failed to load. The contact information for this task is 
 smtp -reference:Error: There were errors during task validation. dbo_history:Error: The package cannot execute because it contains tasks that failed to load.

Comment: @Aswin  this is error I m facing